# BIOS responds to my keyboard input but I get a black screen?

Tags: ubuntu, boot, keyboard, display, bios

I am able to enter the BIOS on my Asus Z-97 Pro motherboard, and I can load Ubuntu by pressing <kbd>F8</kbd> (boot menu), then <kbd>Down</kbd> (select Ubuntu), then <kbd>Enter</kbd> (boot Ubuntu). However, no output is displayed on my monitor during this process. The monitor only starts displaying something once the OS starts loading. Windows 10 (the default boot option) also works the fine.

[edit] I am connected to an NVIDIA 780 TI via DisplayPort. This is where the OS is able to display. When I try to connect to integrated graphics, neither the BIOS nor the OS displays.

Comment: How to do you have your display connected?  Are you using the integrated video or do you have another graphics card installed?

Comment: Sorry, I should have added info about this. I am connected to an NVIDIA 780 TI via DisplayPort. This is where the OS is able to display. When I try to connect to integrated graphics, neither the BIOS nor the OS displays.

Answer (score 0):

I have a suggestion about how to proceed, but be forewarned that this answer is somewhat speculative.  I suspect your motherboard firmware (BIOS) is set to initialize the integrated graphics first, then the add-in graphics card second.  But how to confirm this if you can't see the BIOS display?  To do this, I would suggest temporarily removing your add-in graphics card, connect your display to one of the motherboard video connections, and enter into your BIOS immediately on next boot.  Search through the settings and look for a setting describing which graphics adapter to initialize first.  If you find a setting like this, set it to initialize the add-in card first (and possibly disable the integrated graphics entirely), then quit the BIOS while saving the changes.  After you have made the changes to the BIOS, you can reinstall your add-in card (and be sure to reconnect your display to the add-in card).  Just be sure your machine is safely shutdown before removing and reinstalling your graphics card.